# SQL query for summing the values from two tables and showing the result in pie chart using C#.NET

Tags: c#, sqlite, pie-chart

I have two tables Fruit and Banana in my SQLite database where Fruit.Banana = Banana.Id like following-

```
Fruit

Id  Banana  Mango   Apple
1   10  101 1001
2   11  102 1002
3   11  103 1003
4   12  104 1004
5   13  105 1004
6   13  105 1005
7   14  106 1005
8   14  106 1005


Banana

Id  S   D   DC

10  1   0   0
11  0   1   0
12  0.5 0.5 0
13  1   0   0
14  0   0   1
```

What I want to do is summing all the corresponding values from the columns in Banana(S,D,DC) like following. That is, it counts all the Fruit Id and sums the corresponding values from Banana columns (S,D,DC). I take 3 variables BananaS, BananaD, BananaDC to add the values from S, D, and DC columns from the table Banana.

```
Fruit.Banana = Banana.Id

BananaS = 1+0+0+0.5+1+1+0+0 =3.5 
BananaD = 0+1+1+0.5+0+0+0+0  = 2.5
BananaDC= 0 +0+0+0+0+0+1+1 =2

Total = BananaS+BananaD+BananaDC= 8
```

Then I want to show these values in a pie chart by calculating the percentage of the  values like following-

```
BananaSPercentage = (BananaS*100)/ Total = (3.5*100) /8 = 43.75 %
BananaDPercentage = (BananaD*100)/ Total = (2.5*100) /8 = 31.25 %
BananaDCPercentage = (BananaDC*100)/ Total = (2*100) /8 = 25 %
```

I am doing it in C#.NET. I am a bit confused about the sql queries and the way to use these values to show in pie chart.
Could anyone help me please ?
Are the following queries correct ?

```
Select S, D, DC
From Fruit, Banana
Where Fruit.Banana = Banana.Id

BananaS = BananaS +S
BananaD = BananaD +D
BananaDC = BananaDC +DC
```

I just need to know the correct SQL queries and a smart way to handle them to show in a pie chart.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this (I haven't actually tried this with SQLite, but it works with SQL Server):

To sum up all the values in the `Banana` table, the following statement should do:

```
SELECT SUM(b.S + b.D + b.DC) AS Total, SUM(b.S) AS BananaS, SUM(b.D) AS BananaD, SUM(b.DC) AS BananaDC
FROM
  Fruit f
  INNER JOIN Banana b ON b.ID = f.Banana
```

This returns you the required sums. Execute this query from C# and handle the results accordingly.